# How do I share a chrome tab via AirDrop?

Tags: macos, iphone, google-chrome, airdrop

I'd like to share my current Chrome page on macOS via AirDrop to an iOS device so that I can open it up in mobile Safari.

If I use Safari on a desktop, this is easily done via: Share > AirDrop.

Is there an equally easy way to do this on Chrome?

[How to Send Web Pages from Chrome to Your Phone](https://www.howtogeek.com/349103/how-to-send-web-pages-from-chrome-to-your-phone/) and [others](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/4wrikb/is_there_an_extension_that_lets_me_air_drop_a/d69jwvk/) recommend using a 3rd party tool called Pushbullet. This is cumbersome because it requires an extension to be installed on desktop Chrome, a 3rd party app installed on an iOS device, and will probably not open the page in mobile Safari (i.e. I'm guessing it'll open it up in mobile Chrome).

Handoff can [apparently](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/4wrikb/is_there_an_extension_that_lets_me_air_drop_a/d69e9kt/) solve this problem, but that requires you to  be logged in to the same Apple account on both devices. Is there a way that this can work without being logged in to the same device, just as AirDrop via Safari works?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Open the 'File' menu in Chrome, choose 'Share', then 'AirDrop'.

[image]

Comment: Great solution! This opens it up in Safari on the phone (desired behavior), and has the correct preview image. I guess I was expecting it to be available under the "..." menu on the right rather than looking for it in the File menu.

Comment: use http://sharedrop.io/

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution that requires no 3rd party software:

1. Open AirDrop in finder.
2. Drag the current page from Chrome (via the bookmark/lock icon) on to the device in the AirDrop window.

This will send a `.webloc` file that opens up in Mobile Safari just as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a markdown file (.md extension) on macOS, paste in the URL, and AirDrop it to the device. Then on the device, accept the file and open with "Notes", which will contain a clickable URL.

Alternatively, you could send a .webloc file by completing the below, but it opens a Safari preview within the "Files" application, rather than Safari itself (in iOS 12.2 at least). However, this process requires you to save the webloc file, which is a bit cumbersome to find/delete. Also, the Safari preview closes with upwards screen swipes.

1.) Open AirDrop in finder
2.) Drag the tab's certificate lock icon from Chrome to the device (in AirDrop)